# Save input from a form to a list.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a form where you can enter recipes on food. I want to save the titles of food recipes in a list to the right so that you can press a title and get the whole recipe you saved. Someone who has a good idea of how to proceed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <title>Din digitala receptbok</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="slideDown">
        <header>
          <h1>Din digitala receptbok</h1>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
      <form id="matInput">
        <div>
        <label for="titel">Titel:</label>
        <input type="text" name="titel" id="titel">
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="portioner">Antal portioner:</label>
        <input type="text" name="portioner" id="portioner">
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="ingred">Fyll i ingredienserna här:</label>
        <textarea name="ingred" rows="5" cols="40" id="ingred"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="metod">Tillagningsmetod:</label>
        <textarea name="metod" rows="5" cols="40" id="metod"> </textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="theSubmit">
        <input id="spara" type="submit" value="Spara recept">
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100%-20px);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(../bilder/Optimized-food-salad-restaurant-person.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

header {
  background-color: #efe5e5;
  width: 50vw;
  min-width: 391px;
  height: 84px;
  border-radius: 64px;
  margin: auto;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 2;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px #1b1b4c;
  outline: none;
}

.slideDown {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 232px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  clear: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

input, textarea {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#theSubmit {
  margin-left: 232px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.4);})
  $("button").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);})
  $(".slideDown").slideDown("slow");
  })
```

Comment: what issue you are facing now?

Answer (score 0):

For adding recipes on food, you will need to create a page(html/JSP page) from where you can enter the data as you have created.
Now on clicking on button "Spara recept", the response should go to controller, from where It will be stored in database. And again when you will refresh this page, you will need to retrieve the stored data as you want.

If you don't want to store it in to DB then you can store it on any where in your system(like on excel sheet,.csv file etc).
Like that you can do.

Comment: Yes, if you are interested in php technology then u should learn.
Otherwise if you are interested in java technology so it will be better option for that. @Adam